# Substring method not accepting blank lines or nulls in java?

Tags: java, split

This is not a duplicate, I know how to compare strings, my problems is with using substring and split methods. I am not getting my desired output 
I have a java project where I am reading a csv that has the first 2 columns are populated.

1st column has a path to a image of a receipt. 2nd column has the reciept number.

Problem, i want to count the number of rows where the reciept # is blank. Unfortunately, my code is ignoring the blank cell.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

       String recipetNum = null;

       String[] splitLine = line.split(",", -1);

                                  recipetNum = splitLine[2].substring(20,30).trim();

       if (!recipetNum.matches("[0-9]+") || recipetNum.length() < 8 || recipetNum == "”){



              //Add to error table

}
```

Comment: It would be much easier for you to use a library for parsing the CSV and just access the column (like Apache Commons CSV - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Accessing_column_values_by_index)

Comment: If you know how to compare strings, why do I see `recipetNum == "”`?

Comment: Was this a suggestion solution?

Comment: It leads you in the right direction, yes. But still, my question remains unanswered. Why are you using `recipetNum == "”`?

Comment: Well, I thought "" represents a empty string.

Comment: `==` only compares the value of prìmitive types in Java. When applied to object, it compares their references. Here it will compare the value of the reference `recipetNum` with the value of the reference to the newly created object `""`